# How to install the gnat GPS for Mac using x11?

Tags: macos, ada, gnat

I was in a conference today, and the person talking had a Mac OS X system with the Gnat GPS IDE installed, but the app name in the top tollbar was "X11".

I would like to have GNAT GPS IDE on my Mac.
I dont know how to install it with X11? Any help?

Currently I code in the "Text Editor" app and compile it through terminal using the `gnatmake` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I have GNAT GPL 2012 installed in `/opt/gnat-gpl-2012` and I just say in a Terminal window

```
/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/gps &
```

Up to Lion, X11 came with the OS (I think it may have been an optional install). In Mountain Lion, Apple no longer provide an official X11; however, when I started GPS for the first time on this new machine - as above - I was told how to install XQuartz. It Just Worked.

Comment: Im using 10.8 (Mountain lion) and I have installed xQuartz separately. But I do not understand how to install GNAP GPL 2012? Wich version to download? Thank you

Comment: There is only one GNAT GPL 2012 for Darwin, it's `gnat-gpl-2012-x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-bin.tar.gz` from AdaCore (haven't you got it already?) and it contains GPS. Unpack it, then `sudo ./doinstall` and follow the directions. If you've already done this, GPS will be at `{installprefix}/bin/gps`.

Comment: GNAT GPL for Darwin is already installed and I can compile with no problems. However when trying to execute the command I get an error: http://i49.tinypic.com/2q81rae.png

Comment: my ~/.bashrc is as following
PATH=/usr/local/gnat/bin:$PATH; export PATH

Comment: In my case, `$DISPLAY` is currently set to `/tmp/launch-J4svgJ/org.macosforge.xquartz:0` - I have no idea what part of the XQuartz setup did that! However, since you already have GPS on your path, you should get away with adding `export DISPLAY=:0` to `~/.bashrc`, starting XQuartz by hand (`open -a xquartz` to save time going to `Applications/Utilities`) and then just `gps &`.

Comment: You could test the idea out, of course, by just `export DISPLAY=:0` in the Terminal.